# SQLPLUS login | run script

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I want oracle/sqlplus to run a sql script as soon as I login or connect to a database. How can I achieve that?

In that script I want to set few formatting commands like pagesize, column format etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure a user-specific script that is executed each time you start SQL*Plus

SQL*Plus  looks for that [user profile script](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqpug/configuring-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-B9CC27CF-FA9F-4C2A-9B2C-F7411839C50A) in the directories specified in the `SQLPATH` [environment variable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqpug/configuring-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-B9CC27CF-FA9F-4C2A-9B2C-F7411839C50A) or the equivalent [registry entry](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqpug/configuring-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-A91DD984-84ED-4D67-9983-938FCFC3665E) in Windows